# $f(x + y)f(x − y) = ( f(x) + f(y) )^ 2− 4x^ 2 f(y)$ so why $f(2) \neq 2$?

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Let $f : \mathbb R → \mathbb R$ be a function that satisfies for all $x,y ∈ \mathbb R $ defined as $f(x + y)f(x − y) = 
( f(x) + f(y) )^ 2− 4x^ 2 f(y)$. So, why $f(2) = 2$ is impossible?

Why $f(0) = 0, f(3) = 9, f(5) = 0$ are ok but not $f(2) = 2$?

Comment: Have you tried some basic things like putting $x=y=0$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With $x=y=0$, the relation shows you that $f(0)^2=4f(0)^2$, so $f(0)$ must equal $0$.

Then with $x=y$, the relation shows that $0=4f(x)^2-4x^2f(x)$, so for all $x$, $$f(x)(f(x)-x^2)=0$$

And so for each $x$, either $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)=x^2$.

Comment: Thank you, SO much for this amazing explanation!!☺

Comment: In fact not just $\forall x\colon (f(x)=0\lor f(x)=x^2)$, but in fact $(\forall x\colon f(x)=0)\lor (\forall x\colon f(x)=x^2)$: Assuem $x\ne0$ with  $f(x)=x^2$, and $y\ne0$ with $f(y)=0$. Then $f(x+y)f(x-y)=x^4\ne 0$, hence $f(x+y)\ne0$, $f(x-y)\ne0$, so $x^4=f(x+y)f(x-y)=(x+y)^2(x-y)^2=x^4-2x^2y^2+y^4$, so $y\in\{0, x/\sqrt 2,-x/\sqrt 2\}$. Then $f(x+y)f(y-x)=x^4-4x^2y^2\ne0$, so $x^4-4x^2y^2=(x+y)^2(x-y)^2$. $2x^2y^2+y^4=0$, $y=0$